# DirectX - не удается открыть файл

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

При компиляции проекта в конфигурации  **Release**  и платформе **Win32**(да, во вех остальных случаях работает) получаю следующую ошибку:

> не удается открыть файл "c:\users\userman\source\repos\DirectX
>   Test\Release\DirectX Test.exe"

. Т.е. не получается открыть саму программу, а когда я захожу в каталог, где она должна быть, то ее там просто нет. Пишу на DirectX11 и WinAPI. Проект настраивал по следующей инструкции:

> 1. Во вкладке «Общее» выберите «Набор символов->Использовать набор
>      символов Юникода»
> 2. Во вкладке «Каталоги VC++» выберите «Каталоги
>      включения», далее добавьте следующий элемент (нужно впечатать текст,
>      который идет далее): $(DXSDK_DIR)Include
> 3. Во вкладке «Каталоги VC++»
>      выберите «Каталоги библиотек», далее добавьте следующий элемент
>      (нужно впечатать текст, который идет далее): $(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86
>
> Во вкладке «Компоновщик» выберите пункт «Ввод», затем добавьте
>   следующий список:
>
> ```
> d3d11.lib
> d3dcompiler.lib
> d3dx11d.lib
> d3dx9d.lib
> dxerr.lib
> dxguid.lib
> winmm.lib
> comctl32.lib
> ```

В чем может быть проблема? Как исправить?

Comment: А как лог полностью выглядит?

Comment: @VTT: в смысле полная ошибка? - LINK : fatal error LNK1104: не удается открыть файл "c:\users\userman\source\repos\DirectX Test\Release\DirectX Test.exe"

Comment: То бишь ошибка на этапе линковки происходит, понятно. А антивирус случаем ничего не пресекает?

Comment: @VTT: нет, антивирус молчит. На всякий случай отключил его, но ничего не изменилось. Если интересно, то компилируется без ошибок, ошибка при запуске.

Comment: Убедитесь, что при сборке предыдущая версия софтины не запущена

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: как я уже говорил, exe-шник просто не появляется в папке, где должен быть, поэтому он просто не может быть уже запущен.

Comment: Удалил антивирус - все заработало. Не знаю, почему ситуация не менялась, когда я его отключал. Спасибо всем, кто хотел помочь.